# How to tell Jest not to call a specific function?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a `componentDidMount()` in my React component and it makes an API call and once it receives the response, it calls a function to set the state of the component. I want to test the component without the component calling both  `componentDidMount()` and the function it calls. How do I do it in Jest?

Comment: You need to mock, if you need to help to build the mock, can you say what're you using to make the call? axios, request, native fetch?

Comment: @MiguelAngel axios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a module out of your API calling function. Import it to the Component. [Mock it](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) inside the test.

The mock is a “fake” implementation of the function, which is widely used for testing. So your Component will call mock instead real API call on ComponentDidMount stage. Then you may want to add assertion about mock call.